# Application for Dual citizenship

Tags: united-kingdom, paperwork

Is there an application form that needs to be completed. I was born in the UK but have lived in Australia all of my life. We have permanent residency but I would like dual citizenship with the UK and Now Australia?
I would like to know the process and the cost?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TSE. The information you need is available at https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/citizenship/become-a-citizen Is there something specific to your circumstances that you need help with which the Australian DoHA page doesn’t cover?

Comment: Questions about long term migration, including dual citizenship, belong on [expatriates.se]

Answer (score 2):

First you need to check if you are eligible to become an Australian Citizen, the requirements of this, and the costs.

Details can be found here:
https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/citizenship/become-a-citizen

Then you need to officially apply and follow the instructions which they issue, pay the fees etc.   As part of this process they will ask details of your current citizenships, where you will provide details of your UK citizenship and a copy of your passport (if required)

Assuming your application is successful, then you will officially become an Australian citizen!

You don't need to initially inform the UK of any changes, or that you are now a dual citizen.

However, when/if you apply to renew your UK passport then at this time you need to fill in the section regarding "other citizenship(s)" (the exact name may vary), where you will have to fill in details of your "new" Australian citizenship.
There are no additional fees associated with this.